# Architecture of Android app to display data from WS

Tags: android, web-services, android-permissions

I want to build an `Android` app to display a list of different music singers with some data on each row and a small photo of album. Should be small navigation after selecting an artist, you can go to his albums and then to his songs...

1 - what would be the best architecture design for this kind of app? I tough about implementing it in this way:

When splash screen appears I call to a `web service` to download the information and save it on device `DB`.Then I use `Loaders` to load all this data from `DB`, after load is complete I remove the splash screen and display the list. For each item click I bring the data from `WS` and display it. my question is do I need to involve actually DB for this? and is it good to fetch data for each item selected (singer), if I go back and then press again the same item, do I have to bring again all the data from WS?

2 - Anybody can recommend site where I can learn about architecture of apps, not the linux-android architecture but real apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but give this blogpost a try. It helped me a lot, because it gives you kind of a convention how to design android applications (I'm  coming from rails^^).
http://blog.joanzapata.com/robust-architecture-for-an-android-app/